# Preventing a key binding on a key-map from shadowing global key bindings

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I would like to bind the following key sequence  <kbd>C-x r l</kbd>  to a function called `helm-bookmarks`.

From what I understand, I could do this with a keymap that is triggered with <kbd>C-x</kbd>, e.g.

```
(define-prefix-command 'my_sense_map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'my_sense_map)
(define-key my_sense_map (kbd "r l") 'helm-bookmarks)
```

but this shadows all my other bindings (e.g. <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> or <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> for window splitting), i.e. they stop working.

How can I bind  <kbd>C-x r l</kbd>  to `'helm-bookmarks` **without** changing any other key bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to just set the binding of <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> in the current global map to `helm-bookmarks`:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r l") 'helm-bookmarks)
```

Emacs defines <kbd>C-x</kbd> as a prefix key that uses a keymap stored in the variable `ctl-x-map`, which contains most bindings for key sequences starting with <kbd>C-x</kbd>. If you re-define it so that it uses a new keymap with no entries, you will lose all those bindings stored in `ctl-x-map`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there in general a way to look up a keymap associated/triggered by a specific command?

Comment: You will be able to start by looking up your key sequence using `C-h b` (`describe-bindings`). It will show what key sequences each current keymap defines, although it just gives the descriptive names of keymaps.